# Inverse vs preimage

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Define $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x^2$. Then does $f^{-1}(x)=\{-\sqrt{x},\sqrt{x}\}$ (the preimage of $f$) or is it undefined since it targets multiple elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is not injective. So, $f^{-1}(x)$ is in fact so-called *multifunction* (which values are sets, not necessarily single numbers). Another sense of understanding $f^{-1}(x)$ here is to treat it as an invesse image of a singleton $\{x\}$: $$f^{-1}\bigl(\{x\}\bigr)=\{-\sqrt{x},\ \sqrt{x}\}.$$

If the function is a bijection then the inverse images of singletons are singletons, too. Then in this case we can say about the inverse function.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. So could we say that $f^{-1}$ is undefined if we interpret is as a function (since $f$ is not injective) but well defined if we interpret it as a multifunction? If so, when do we make each of these interpretations?

Comment: In differential equations, for instance.

Comment: I don't understand. Is your answer "Yes" to the first question? And which interpretation do you say we make in differential equations?

Comment: I have in mind that the understanding $f^{-1}$ as multifunction is important in initial conditions for differential equations. Also in the implicit function theory.